# Ubuntu Samba copied files inaccessible

Tags: permissions, samba, smb

When i copy a file on ubuntu Samba file server, i can't open it from any client (windows)
The file displays as a folder which is inaccessible.

Newly created files or folders do not cause problems.

There seems to be a bug report on it from 1 year ago...
but the link to the solution is not valid anymore.

I have seen many similar questions, but have not yet found an answer.

```
[global]
server min protocol = SMB2
# this hides the files in windows

# server min protocol = SMB2
# this displays the files as inaccessable in windows
```

Edit:
samba version: 4.11.6
Ubuntu version: 20.04.2 LTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you post a question about Samba please tell people either which version of samba you are using or which version of Ubuntu you are using.

This workaround is about Ubuntu 19.04 onward:

Edit /etc/samba/smb.conf and right under the workgroup = WORKGROUP line add this one:

```
store dos attributes = No
```

Then restart smbd: `sudo service smbd restart`

This won't fix the files that are already there but all new files should save correctly.

Comment: Thank you! Working perfect now.